# How to add user specific arguments in the config.yaml file on Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am looking at the documentation for the AI platform, and [how to run training jobs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-jobs)
I am looking at the section: **Formatting your configuration parameters**

There, it is shown how to specify your input parameters in a config.yaml file. It is only shown for the gcloud specific parameters. How can the USER_ARGS be added to the config.yaml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide custom args in a config file by adding an "args" list under trainingInput, like this:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: complex_model_m
  workerType: complex_model_m
  parameterServerType: large_model
  workerCount: 9
  parameterServerCount: 3
  runtimeVersion: '1.14'
  pythonVersion: '3.5'
  args:
   - '--neuralNetLayers=50000'
   - '--tileUniverseWithPaperclips=False'
```

The config.yaml file is a Job resource. Most of the interesting parameters are in TrainingInput -- the full TrainingInput spec is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#traininginput

Hope that helps. Happy learning!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.